# WooCommerce admin order page - notify and list new orders when placed

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to notify the admin whenever an order is being placed. I want the small icon which tell the number of orders to be incremented and the new order being listed on the order list. I do not know what action hooks and filter I can use to do such task!!!

I found the **woocommerce_new_order** action while I am searching here but I do not how can I create such visual effects using that action!

I expected to have the information that I can utilize to get the job done!

Comment: Maybe you can try this free plugin: "New Order Notification for Woocommerce". Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Appreciating your help :). I will try it and if it suffice my needs I will mark your post as a solution :). Thanks again for your time and consideration wishing you a happy day!